# Database Tuning Advisor user permissions

Tags: sql-server, permissions, database-tuning-advisor

I was asked to create an account to use Database Tuning Advisor.
I red on technet but I don't understand which permission do I have to give.

I tried to login with this new user, but trying to list tables, I always get warning about there are no user tables available.
If I give db_owner to the user the tables are listed.

Thanks for help.

Bye

Answer (score 3):

From BOL : [Permissions Required to Run Database Engine Tuning Advisor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190987%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

> After you install SQL Server, a user who is a member of the sysadmin fixed server role must launch Database Engine Tuning Advisor before anyone else. When the sysadmin user launches Database Engine Tuning Advisor that action initializes the application for use by others. After Database Engine Tuning Advisor is initialized, **any user who is a member of the db_owner fixed database role can use it to tune tables on databases they own**. For more information about initializing Database Engine Tuning Advisor.